# get subheading text based on an element in container

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

This is where I'm stuck from this repeated section of code  :

```html
<span class="help-block"></span>
<h5 class="omb_authTitle">prettyname </h5>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check size_listing"></i></span>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_uglyname" name="uglyname">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option selected="" value="Yes">yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I used Beautifulsoup to create a dictionary, like so:

```
{'uglyname' : 'Yes'}
```

I searched the `name` attributes from a list I have using select_one, then get the selected value of the dropdown menu.

but what I would like better is the text in `h5` as the key, like so:

```
{'prettyname': 'Yes'}
```

How can I go to that specific `h5` from that unique name in the `div`?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be simpler to iterate the h5's than to go back "up" to get them. Css always goes down, unlike xpath which can go up or down..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`:has()`](https://facelessuser.github.io/soupsieve/selectors/#has) pseudo-class. `:has()` will look ahead to see if the selector within it is true.  Here we target the `h5` element we want and look under the adjacent sibling `div` and look under the `div`'s direct `select` child and compare the attribute. Notice we use a relative selector within `:has()` by preceding the selector with the adjacent sibling combinator `+`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<span class="help-block"></span>
<h5 class="omb_authTitle">prettyname </h5>
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-check size_listing"></i></span>
    <select class="form-control" id="id_uglyname" name="uglyname">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option selected="" value="Yes">yes</option>
        <option value="No">No</option>
    </select>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select_one('h5:has(+ div > select[name=uglyname])'))
```

Output

```
<h5 class="omb_authTitle">prettyname </h5>
```

Comment: I've been searching for hours, never seen  this  :has ()  mentioned anywhere so far. Works in my code, thank you so much :)

Comment: It was originally proposed in the CSS spec, but was abandoned for most likely performance in styling. But for scraping it is quite useful.